# Javascript screen dimensions without toolbar

Tags: javascript, window, screen

I need to get screen dimension of my screen without windows toolbar at bottom of it. I was trying with following but didn't worked:

```
var W = $(window).width();
var H = $(window).height();
```

Here I had opened one window with height of `H/2`, take a look:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) to the rescue!

```
var width = screen.availWidth;
var height = screen.availHeight;
```

Vanilla JS saved the internet, because it removes the limitations of jQuery.

Comment: This gives you full screen width/height. I need WITHOUT TOOLBAR :)